# Power Series: $\sum_1^{\infty} (x)^{n}\frac{n^3}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

I just started learning about the power series, can someone help me with finding the radius of convergence and interval of convergence?

So I am stuck on the radius of convergence because apparently I got a 0 for the limit? I don't know if I did anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: I just thought that to find a radius of convergence, there has to be an "x" equation left over from when u do the root or ratio test so you can compare it it to >1 and <1 and get the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ratio test $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{x^{n+1}n!\left(n+1\right)^{3}}{\left(n+1\right)!x^{n}n^{3}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{x}{n+1}\right|=0
 $$ so the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and the interval of convergence is $\left(-\infty,\infty\right).$

Comment: oh so if the test renders 0 then the radius of convergence is infinity? why is that so?

Comment: @Elsa See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence